# How to filter ip public and ip private with python

Tags: python

i have a file (list_ip.txt) which contains only public ip lists and ip private. I want to split one file into 2 files. one file (ip_public.txt) contains public ip, one file (ip_private.txt) again contains ip private. how do i do it?
contents of ip_list.txt :

```
192.168.14.43
104.244.xxx.xxx
192.168.10.54
38.102.xxx.xxx
192.168.13.232
144.217.xxx.xxx
10.100.40.93
54.171.xxx.xxx
10.100.xxx.xxx
183.61.xxx.xxx
10.100.xxx.xxx
136.243.xxx.xxx
10.40.xxx.xxx
185.75.xxx.xxx
```

this is my code :

```
import csv

file = open('list_ip.txt', 'r')
ipprivate = open('ip_private.txt', 'w')
ippublic = open('ip_public.txt', 'w')

def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
    start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
    end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))

    for i in range(4):
        if start[i] > end[i]:
            start, end = end, start
        break

    temp = start
    ip_range = []

    ip_range.append(start_ip)
    while temp != end:
    start[3] += 1
    for i in (3, 2, 1):
        if temp[i] == 256:
            temp[i] = 0
            temp[i-1] += 1
            ip_range.append(“.”.join(map(str, temp))
)

    return ip_range

iprange = ipRange("192.168.0.0","192.168.255.255")
iprange2 = ipRange("172.16.0.0","172.31.255.255")
iprange3 = ipRange("10.0.0.0","10.255.255.255")

for line in file:
    if line == iprange:
        ipprivate.write(line)
    if line == iprange2:
        ipprivate.write(line)
    if line == iprange3:
        ipprivate.write(line
    else:
        ippublic.write(line)
file.close()
ipprivate.close()
ippublic.close()
```

Comment: Show some of the contents. We have no idea how is this formatted.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems that you want SO community to do work for you without even trying yourself. You should make your problem more specific by providing problems that you've faced.

Comment: A sample of the input file could be useful. Thanks!

Comment: @vishes_shell I've tried, I'll edit and enter the code I've created

Comment: @RaúlReguilloCarmona briefly, I will edit this post

Comment: need the list_ip.txt contents sample.

Comment: If you're using `python 3` there's [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module! You can check each ip with [`is_private`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.is_private).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to check if the IP falls in the range of private IP address space.
[image: private ip range]

And this is simple to do. Here is an example (considering the IPs are on separate lines):

```
allfp = open('all.txt')
publicfp = open('public.txt', 'w')
privatefp = open('private.txt', 'w')

def is_public_ip(ip):
    ip = list(map(int, ip.strip().split('.')[:2]))
    if ip[0] == 10: return False
    if ip[0] == 172 and ip[1] in range(16, 32): return False
    if ip[0] == 192 and ip[1] == 168: return False
    return True

for line in allfp:
    if is_public_ip(line):
        publicfp.write(line)
    else:
        privatefp.write(line)

allfp.close()
publicfp.close()
privatefp.close()
```

Edit: This code assumes that the contents of the input file are valid IP addresses and thus does not check for the validity of the IPs.

Comment: thank you sir, its code can work. but I am each confused why there should be parameters list(map(int, ip.strip().split('.'))) ?

Comment: It is splitting the the string `ip` into 4 and turning them to integers for comparison.

Comment: oh, mean when ip 192.168.1.1 in split based (.) into 4 parts. if the first part == 192 then it will proceed to the second part. if the second part == 168 it will automatically belong to ip private immediately. if parts one and two are not equal to 192 and 168 then it will automatically belong to ip public. thanks sir for explanation